# I am interested in a more optimized solution for sum of all fizzbuzz numbers in a given range

Tags: c#, algorithm, sum, fizzbuzz

The number ***fizzbuzz*** is composed of two numbers that is **fizz** and **buzz**.

**fizz** represents the numbers that are ***divisible by*** **3** and **buzz** are the numbers that are ***divisible by*** **5**.

combining both **fizzbuzz**, are the numbers that is **divisible by both 3 and 5**. So how can we get all the **fizzbuzz** numbers sum in a given range.

Comment: Hi. Try calculating the first fizzbuzz number without using a loop, then to find the next one you only have to increase it by 15, and then another 15, etc. until you've reached or passed the maximum range value.

Comment: Thanks that will be better and more optimized solution.

Comment: Hi, it is fine to have your current approach as part of the question (it is actually indicated to do so, in order to prove that you made some effort) -- as it was before the edit. You should just mention at the end of the question that "I am interested in a more optimized solution".

Comment: If you need to ask about FizzBuzz, and similar exercises, that may indicate that you need to learn a bit more about the basics. Jeff Atwood, who invented the original FizzBuzz exercise, [wrote about that](https://blog.codinghorror.com/fizzbuzz-the-programmers-stairway-to-heaven/).

Comment: Do you know anything  about sum of arithmetic progression?

Comment: yes, I know about arithmetic progression

Comment: I would suggest writing your current code and submitting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @vijay pratap So apply this knowledge to the sequence of values `k*15`

Answer (score 2):

The fizzbuzz numbers which are less or equal to N are integers between 0 and N that are divisible by 15. Their sum is `sum(15*i for i = 1 to N/15)` That's equal to `15*sum(i for i i=1 to N/15)`, or `15*(N/15)*(1+N/15)/2`. (Note, here `/` means rounding down integer division).

The sum of fizzbuzz numbers in the range `[a, b]` (that is, numbers greater than or equal to `a` and less than or equal to `b`), is equal to the sum of the fizzbuzz numbers less than or equal to `b` minus the sum of fizzbuzz numbers less than or equal to `a-1`. That's `15*(b/15)*(1+b/15)/2 - 15*((a-1)/15)*(1+(a-1)/15)/2` using the result in the first paragraph.